# C++ Representing Optional Objects

Tags: c++, option-type, representation

I have a [C++ project](http://github.com/jehugaleahsa/spider-cpp). I work on the project to teach myself about building a semi-realistic program in C++. It downloads content recursively from a website.

Each download has a URL for the content to download, as well as a URL for the referrer (or the URL of the page that the content was extracted from).

There is always a referrer unless it's the very first URL. I had been cheating and just treating the first URL as its own referrer. I recently changed the URL class to have a blank (or empty) representation. This feels like a hack.

Is there a way to represent optional objects in C++ without:

- Using pointers?
- Wasting space for the invalid object?
- or Making a "blank" version of the object?

Comment: W\O: Using pointers? IMHO not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use boost::optional. boost is well-respected 3rd party library; often regarded as a prototype for new stl functions: See Ralph's answer std::optional is available with new C++.

See http://www.boost.org/

Comment: I originally posted that as a comment, but won't that waste space for the "blank" version? Not that I think it is a serious problem, but it is one of the specific requirements of the question.

Comment: No. boost::optional uses a pointer, set to NULL as appropriate, in its implementation. Don't know how std::optional works.

Comment: @Bathsheba I'm just trying to avoid reinventing established conventions. I used `unique_ptr` but decided it made the code look lopsided. I felt it wasn't explicitly saying "this field is optional". Instead it looked like a memory management technique.

Answer (score 5):

Use the `std::optional` template, if you have a C++14 compiler. If not you can use `boost::optional` or `std::unique_ptr`. You cannot avoid both using pointers and wasting space for the invalid object. [`std::optional`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional) will contain the optional object, [`std::unique_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) will obviously point to it.